# What's the meaning of `try something in a bottle`?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What's the meaning of `try something in a bottle`?

In  [there](https://www.airshipit.org/) :

> TRY AIRSHIP IN A BOTTLE

what's the meaning of it?

Comment: Thanks for the question!  You can improve the question by including the source of the quotation.   I've added my shot at an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to an internet search, "Airship-in-a-bottle" is a special version of a computer software program called "Airship".

> ### Airship in a Bottle
>
> Use the `airship-in-a-bottle.sh` script to automatically deploy a demonstration version of Airship. It will attempt to detect the required environment settings and deploy an instance of Airship, including running a demo instance of OpenStack (using OpenStack Helm), and creating a simple Virtual Machine.
>
> --- https://opendev.org/airship/treasuremap/src/branch/master/tools/deployment/aiab#airship-in-a-bottle

So, "**Airship**" is the name of a program, and

"**In a bottle**" means a special version of the program where it is **isolated** from other things on the computer (other programs, other files, etc.).

This concept is similar to the following well-known uses of the "bottle" idea:

## **Message in a bottle**

A piece of paper is sealed into a bottle and dropped in the ocean.  It can travel for thousands of miles and many years without any interaction from its surroundings (the water will ruin the paper).    (See more at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_in_a_bottle)).

## **Ship in a bottle**

> [image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b5/Buddelschiff_2012_PD_06.JPG/330px-Buddelschiff_2012_PD_06.JPG]

See the interesting [Wikipedia article, "Impossible bottle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_bottle#Ship_in_a_bottle).

And, just for fun:

## **Bottle episode of a TV show**

A [bottle episode of a TV show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottle_episode) occurs when an episode is produced 'in very little time at very little cost, "as in pulling an episode right out of a bottle like a genie."'  There are usually no guest stars, so there is almost no ***interaction with the world outside*** the main actors in a small, isolated setting.   This puts the episode in **isolation** from the rest of the show's stories, with no relationship to the larger story (arc) of a show.   (*Star Trek* literally made an episode titled "Ship in a Bottle".)<sup>([More Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottle_episode#Examples))</sup>

## Synonyms

In computing, you can read more about **isolating your software** by understanding the concepts behind **virtual machines**, **container software**, or the popular implementation of these, *Docker*.

---

## Try XYZ

> Try Airship-in-a-Bottle

I assume you understand the use of the word 'try' in the original quotation, but for those who don't, this is a **verb** that is a command (or suggestion):

> Try this pizza.
>
> Try working harder.
>
> Try me.